# Accessing users friends work history using GRAPH API 2.3

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How can I get the users friends work history? Currently I tried this in the Graph api explorer:

```
GET /me/taggable_friends?fields=id,name,work&acess_token...
```

and the query returns the friends, but don't show any job.

The response returns me somethin like this:

```
"data": [
{
  "id": "<some-long-string>", 
  "name": "<name>"
},
```

I tried to do this:

```
GET /<the-some-long-string>...
```

And the response says me that the user id is incorrect. Googling I didn't found anything :'(

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Facebook Developers:

> "message": "(#10) To use taggable_friends on behalf of people who are
>   not admins, developers and testers of your app, your use of this
>   endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this
>   feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable
>   features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review"